# Confusing terminology of TimeSeries: "Smoothing" and "Differencing"

Tags: time-series, arima, terminology, moving-average

I studied MA, AR, ARIMA, SARIMA to forecast products demand using `python`, but recently I encountered the `smoothing`, using `moving average`(by python `pd.rolling.mean()`) and following things especially made me confused:

1. Does "moving average" for smoothing indicate MA model?
2. if I need to do difference, is it correct I apply ARIMA model to that TimeSeries?
3. Why does people use `rolling.mean()`, `std()`, `pd.diff()` when dealing with `timeseries` data with trend and seasonality, not SARIMA model?